# Inserting datetime in sqlite database from date and time picker android

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

Am developing android ToDO List App 
need help from you
i have created table as:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE todos (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, todo TEXT NOT NULL, datetime DATETIME NOT NILL );");
```

and have insert `todo Text NOT NULL` in this

```
// DAO
private TodoDAO dao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_todo);

    // Create DAO object
    dao = new TodoDAO(this);

    todoText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newTodoText);
    addNewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewTodoButton);

    datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    timepicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

    addNewButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (addNewButton.isPressed()) {
        // Get entered text
        String todoTextValue = todoText.getText().toString();
        todoText.setText("");

        // Add text to the database
        dao.createTodo(todoTextValue);
        }
        }
```

then how to get datetime values to this activity
and inserting to DataBase

TodoDAO.java

```
   public TodoDAO(Context context) {
       dbHelper = new TodoSQLiteHelper(context);
       db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   }

   // Close the db
   public void close() {
       db.close();
   }

   public void createTodo(String todoText) {
       ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
       contentValues.put("todo", todoText);
       // Insert into DB
       db.insert("todos", null, contentValues);
   }
```

help me to insert `DATETIME` the datetime format to database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SimpleDataFormat to get the date in the format sqlite accepts and store it with that. See Method 3 here: http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/